# Separable ODE Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I really do not how to solve this equation in analytical ways? Could anyone help me give the analytical solution of the following equations?
$$2\frac{da}{dt}-a-\frac{a^5}{16}=0$$

Comment: **Hint:** This is a Separable Equation. Separate and integrate.

Comment: Yeah, but I do not know how to separate and then integrate both sides,could you help me please?

Comment: I can get the equality like this$$\frac{da}{a(16+a^4)}=\frac{dt}{32}$$,then how to deduce the LHS integral? Indeed, how to calculate the integral$$\int \frac{da}{a(16+a^4)}$$

Comment: Maybe Partial fraction decomposition will help you. See this wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Comment: Quadrillion...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, in fact, a very easy one
$$2\frac{da}{dt}=a+\frac{a^{5}}{16}$$
$$t+c=32\int\frac{da}{a(16+a^4)}$$
To evaluate the integral, let $a^{4}=z$, than
$$t+c=8\int\frac{dz}{z(16+z)}=\frac{1}{2}\int\Big(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z+16}\Big)dz=\frac{1}{2}\ln{\frac{z}{z+16}}+c'=\frac{1}{2}\ln{\frac{a^{4}}{a^{4}+16}}+c'$$ 
Thus
$$a(t)=\pm\frac{2e^{t/2}}{(C-e^{2t})^{1/4}}$$
Sorry if i've messed somewhere with algebra, factors of two, etc., a little bit in a hurry...